# display records based on ranks and also delete duplicated data

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table like this

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | rank |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | A    | X    |    4 |
|    2 | C    | Y    |    3 |
|    2 | C    | Y    |    3 |
|      | A    | X    |    3 |
|    1 | B    | Z    |    2 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

(5 rows)

I need o/p like this

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | rank |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | A    | X    |    4 |
|    2 | C    | Y    |    3 |
|    1 | B    | Z    |    2 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

so that I written query like below

```
select col1,col2,col3,rank,dense_rank() over(order by rank desc) from table1;
```

but its not giving proper o/p

Answer (score 1):

try this !!

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,max(a.rank) as rank 
          from [dbo].[5] a join [dbo].[5] b 
              on a.col1=b.col1 group by a.col1,a.col2,a.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need aggregation with max():

```
select
    col1,col2,col3,
    max(rnk)
from table1
group by col1,col2,col3
```

If you could have different values of `col1` for one combination of `col2, col3`, then `distinct on` is what you need:

```
select distinct on (col2, col3)
    col1,col2,col3,
    rnk
from table1
order by col2, col3, rnk desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/49277/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

The following should match what you are looking for:

```
select col1,col2,col3,rank,dense_rank() over(order by rank desc) from table1
 WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

You can also use numeric aliases in your order by clause if you want one.